# How can I load model both yolov5 and yolov7

Tags: python, yolo, yolov5, yolov7

When I load yolov5 and yolov7 in python, I get error like this.

Can't get attribute 'MP' on <module 'models.common' from '/workspace/yolov5/models/common.py'>

'MP' is yolov7 attribute...

How can I load yolov7/models/common.py ?

How can I set models.commmon.py python PATH?

Answer (score 0):

create new environment and using this environment download requerments.txt. I think this will work. For example, with anaconda you can use this code to create new environment:

```
conda create -n name_environment python-3.9
```

activate this environment:

```
conda activate name_environment
```

then download libraries